# Is it acceptable to use a custom versioning scheme in a .Net library to be published in the common NuGet repository?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, versioning, convention

I have came to a somewhat original version numbering scheme for my projects:

```
Major.Year.Month.Build
```

e.g.

```
2.2017.3.4
```

Which means this is a fourth build of the second generation (meaning serious breaking changes as compared to the 1.*.*.* branch, it may be a totally different app for the same task actually, I just don't want to rename it in something like MyApp2) app made in March of 2017.

I would also love to include the month number but 5-part version numbers seem to be unsupported by Visual Studio / .NET Framework or the Win32 version data resource format.

I've never seen anything like this verbose hybrid of classic and date-based versioning (YEAR-RELEASE is somewhat alike but not much) and suspect that's because it may happen to be too inconvenient, counter-intuitive, untidy-looking or something like that for many, the question is whether this is the case and if the problem is serious enough to make this way of versioning actually discouraged strongly by rules of some sort or the informal convention of the community.

Can I use this way of versioning in a library I plan to publish or is there an established convention that I should comply to?

Comment: @ Ivan, any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from answer? If not, Would you please let me know more information about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

http://semver.org/  is recommended for versioning NuGet packages.

It has similar concepts to what you mentioned, the first number is for major breaking changes. Additional info such as the date can be added in the release labels or metadata.

Comment: I have been considering this before my aforementioned hybrid of semver + date has came into my mind. I (given my own personal taste alone, I don't mean I'm right at all) find it (my version format) much more intuitive and, this way, practical an pleasant to use (both as a developer having to invent version numbers and as a consumer willing to have a basic clue of the app obsolesce/relevance in one sight at its version number). However I still feel my version looks a way to bizarre so I am feeling like keeping with the convention (semver) anyway.

Comment: Although I accept your answer practically and am going to go this way actually, for sake of knowledge integrity I would still appreciate if you, given your experience in the NuGet community (mine just begins), could include a paragraph with a logically formal answer to my question: whether or not using a unconventional (non-semver in particular) versioning scheme is allowed. I will approve your answer then (I feel like I can't do so otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it acceptable to use a custom versioning scheme in a .Net library to be published in the common NuGet repository?

**The answer is Yes, but not recommended.** The NuGet Gallery is open-source website for the central package repository used by all package authors and consumers. We could publish Customized packages to the common NuGet repository. For more convenient and effective management package updates, we need to do to start using Semantic Versioning is to declare that you are doing so and then follow the rules.
Just as Justin Emgarten`s suggestion, in the [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/):

> For this system to work, you first need to declare a public API. This may consist of documentation or be enforced by the code itself. Regardless, it is important that this API be clear and precise. Once you identify your public API, you communicate changes to it with specific increments to your version number. Consider a version format of X.Y.Z (Major.Minor.Patch). Bug fixes not affecting the API increment the patch version, backwards compatible API additions/changes increment the minor version, and backwards incompatible API changes increment the major version.

With those rules, we could easy to communicate your intentions to the users of your package updates. If you use a custom versioning “`Major.Year.Month.Build`”, other customers will lose your intentions of your package updates. So the answer is yes but not recommended.